# jQuery Smooth Scroll not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add smooth scrolling to named anchors in my site.  I have a jQuery plug in that simply calls on internal named anchors and animates the html and body.  I've used it before on other sites and it works fine, but I can't figure out why it isn't working here.  Strangely enough, the same code works fine in Apple Safari but not Google Chrome.  All the other sites I have used this on work fine in Chrome.  I cannot figure this out one.

Below are is my HTML.  It is simply a div with an  tag and the matching anchor point in the div below.

```html
<div id="slide1" class="slide">
<a href="#section">
<div id="scrollbtn">
<img src="images/downarrow.png" alt="Down Arrow">
</div>
</a>
</div>


<div id="main">
<a id="section" class="link"></a>
<p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Below is the jQuery plug-in.  It has worked fine in other sites that I've used and I can't see why it isn't working here.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing your selector from $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])') to just $('a') and test it out. Sometimes it's just the selector that has a fault that you can't pick up.

Comment: you need to quote the value of your attribute selectors `$('a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"]')`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {
    $('a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 800);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Is another way to make it.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Rubio/pen/qZvpyq)

Leave you a Codepen working. Let me know what's giving you issues.

Comment: It still didn't work.  I think it is something in Chrome that is blocking it.  It doesn't jump to the anchor without the scrolling, it just doesn't move.

Comment: I've updated. Take a look to the codepen and if still doesn't work, let me know to see what's happening.

Comment: It still isn't working.  It is not even that the code isn't working and it is just jumping right to the anchor, the page just doesn't move.  When I take the code out, it jumps right to the correct spot.

Comment: Never mind.  I just figured it out.  I had some parallaxing on the same page and the WebGL must have been interfering with the jQuery.